# NavigationController Stack

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

First of all, sorry for my bad english. I'll try to explain my question:

I have a RootViewController (Navigation based project). So, it shows the tableview and when the user select a row of the table (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) y do the following to show the next view:

```
NextViewController *nextView = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
[nextView release];
```

What happens if the user select the back button of the navigationbar and select again the row, and do this repeatedly? A lot of new views (instances of NextViewController) is being created (a lot of memory allocating)? Or is he just navigating the stack?

Can you help me? I dont want to waste memory in that way (if is the case).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user toggles back and forth from your RootViewController to a NextViewController repeatedly, here's what happens:

1. The NextViewController is created (`alloc`'d) in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. Because you called an `init` method on it, you're responsible for releasing it.
2. You push `nextView` onto the navigation controller stack, which retains it.
3. You release `nextView`, so the only thing with a retain on it is the navigation controller.
4. Once your user moves back from the NextViewController, the navigation controller releases it. Now nothing is retaining `nextView`, so it gets `dealloc`'d. The memory is freed.

Basically, you do create a NextViewController every time your user moves back and forth (you're not "just navigating the stack," since objects *are* changing each time), but you're not leaking a large amount of memory or holding on to each controller you create. Your memory usage here is fine.